how to add a personal color to usecolortheme structure
I recently discovered how to use the structure color theme in beamer where I can change the overall color palette based on different xcolor variables. However, these are limited to:

dvipsnames
svgnames
x11names

Is there a way to set a personal color for the presentation structure, for instance using \definecolor or similar? Below, how I implemented my color theme with structure:
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme[named=BlueViolet]{structure}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\definecolor{SpaceCadet}{HTML}{17355a} %how can I use this instead of BlueViolet?
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}

\title[xxx]{FLASH TALK}
\author[Surname, Given Name]{Given Name Surname}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,shadow=true,rounded=true]
\makeatother

\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{author}{shape=\bfseries,size=\normalsize}

\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=anti-flashwhite}
\setbeamerfont{title}{shape=\bfseries,size=\LARGE}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
   \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}


You can define your desired colour and pass it to the structure colour theme:
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\definecolor{quack}{RGB}{145,224,42}
\usecolortheme[named=quack]{structure}

\title{Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
   \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}



thanks a lot. The fault is on my this time, I did exactly the same as you but left the \definecolor after the \usecolortheme… and, thus, got an error. So, this goes back to me missing on the situations in which LaTex requires positional information. E. g. a command must be issued before another to work

@Matteo If you would minimise your examples to the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem, you'd have a good chance to spot such problems yourself
